# new to snowflake - issue with SQL statement with joins and pivoting values

Tags: sql, join, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to model product by have a product table linking to characteristic table with 3 many to many table

eg

- Product (productId, brand, description, model)
- ProductCharacteristic (productId, characteristicId)
- Characteristic (characteristicId, type, name, value)

From this structure I'm trying pivot back into one result to show product fields with and characteristic.type characteristic.value into a select statement.

For example:

```
select distinct 
    p.ProductId, p.name, p.description, p.brand, p.model, body, DoorNum
from    
    Product p
left join   
    ProductionCharacteristic pc on p.ProductId = pc.ProductId,
    (select CharacteristicId, "'Body'" as body, "'DoorNum'" as DoorNum  
     from Characteristic c
     pivot (max(c.name) for c.type IN ('Body' , 'DoorNum')))  temp
where  
    pc.CharacteristicId = temp.CharacteristicId
```

Issue1: is any_Value an Aggregate function? it pivot doesnt like it, i'm using max() instead
Issue2: the above select returns 3 rows. is there a way flatten it down to one record?

Comment: Please ask 1 question per post. Please in code questions give a [mre]. Why can't you tell what aggregates you have available? See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts. "flatten it down to one record" This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. But we can expect an easily googled SO faq. (Likely finding GROUP_CONCAT().)

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After an OUTER JOIN ON, a WHERE or INNER JOIN that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS Mixing implicit cross join (comma) with keyword joins is asking for trouble--the former has lower precedence than the latter.

Comment: It might be worth noting that in your table list you have ProductCharacteristic, but in your SQL you have ProductionCharacteristic.

Comment: Also the Product table doesn't have a "name" column

Comment: ANY_VALUE() is an aggregate function, but doesn't work inside the context of PIVOT
https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008uVHTYSA4/anyvalue-does-not-work-on-pivot

Comment: If you can provide an expected output from a mock data input, that would be very helpful for us.  At this point, I can suggest you take a look at the LISTAGG function and get away from using PIVOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Notes

1. I must insist that you ***NEVER*** use mixed join expressions.  Meaning that if you are going to use the keywords `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` *then don't use* `,` and vice versa.
2. You didn't make it clear what you expected your output to look like so I am going with a comma separated list, but will also be showing how you can use an array.
3. I put this in as a comment, but worth repeating: ANY_VALUE() is an aggregate function, but doesn't work inside the context of PIVOT
   https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008uVHTYSA4/anyvalue-does-not-work-on-pivot

---

### Query Options

#### Option 1 - Inline Pivot (Not recommended as it's harder to read and the pivot sub-query can't be reused)

```
select 
    p.ProductId
    , p.name
    , p.description
    , p.brand
    , p.model
    , listagg(temp.body,', ') as body
    , listagg(temp.DoorNum,', ') as doornum1
    , arrayagg(temp.DoorNum) as doornum2
from    
    Product p
left join
    ProductionCharacteristic pc 
        on p.ProductId = pc.ProductId
join (
      select CharacteristicId, body, doornum
      from Characteristic c
      pivot (max(c.name) for c.type IN ('Body' , 'DoorNum')) as p (CharacteristicId, value, body, doornum)
    )  temp
    on pc.CharacteristicId = temp.CharacteristicId
group by 1,2,3,4,5
;
```

#### Option 2 - Pivot in CTE (Recommended)

```
with temp as (
  select CharacteristicId, body, doornum
  from Characteristic c
  pivot (max(c.name) for c.type IN ('Body' , 'DoorNum')) as p (CharacteristicId, value, body, doornum)
)
select 
    p.ProductId
    , p.name
    , p.description
    , p.brand
    , p.model
    , listagg(temp.body,', ') as body
    , listagg(temp.DoorNum,', ') as doornum1
    , arrayagg(temp.DoorNum) as doornum2
from    
    Product p
left join
    ProductionCharacteristic pc 
        on p.ProductId = pc.ProductId
join temp
    on pc.CharacteristicId = temp.CharacteristicId
group by 1,2,3,4,5
;
```

#### Option 3 - Lateral Join (Like a correlated subquery)

```
select 
    p.ProductId
    , p.name
    , p.description
    , p.brand
    , p.model
    , temp.body
    , temp.doornum1
    , temp.doornum2
from    
    Product p
join lateral (
    select listagg(iff(type = 'Body',name,null),', ') as body
        ,listagg(iff(type = 'DoorNum',name,null),', ') as doornum1
        ,arrayagg(iff(type = 'DoorNum',name,null)) as doornum2
    from Characteristic c
    join ProductionCharacteristic pc 
            on pc.CharacteristicId = c.CharacteristicId
    where p.ProductId = pc.ProductId
    ) temp
;
```

Hope this helps.